# Which filter and what parameters should I use to deinterlace this video?

Tags: encoding

I want to use a small part of this video:

.
It has very bad interlacing that I need to get rid of.

I downloaded the mp4 file, which is 1920x1080, 29.971 fps. I don't know much about video processing, and the only thing I can use is avidemux. So I followed this tutorial: http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=tutorial:deinterlacing_video .
I tried the Decomb Telecide filter as the tutorial says, selecting "No strategy" and leaving the other options as default. But it didn't get rid of the interlacing. Then I tried the Yadif filter, and then both filters together, and none of these gave any improvement to the video. The interlacing is still very bad, and I don't know why. I've used Yadif filter on other Youtube videos before, and it works every time except this one.

Which filter and what options should I choose to deinterlace this video properly?

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with filters. The only way to deinterlace this video correctly, is by having the original footage. Right now you are using a .mp4 footage, it was already encoded by Youtube (this encoding process includes a deinterlacing too). So, technically you already are using a deinterlaced video.

If you deinterlace it again, it is like you were trying to put an egg white and yolk inside the eggshell, sure you can do it, but you won't get correct results.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lost cause since the interlaced video got already compressed by youtube destroying the pattern, you will not get a clean progressive video from this.

Comment: I would think so, but the OP says: *I've used Yadif filter on other Youtube videos before, and it works every time except this one.*